# subversion version number question

Tags: subversive

I am using SVN, Visual Studio, and VisualSVN plugin for VS.
Is it possible to set things up where each item under control, say a file, will have its own sequential version number, which is independent from other items under control.
For example, I want foo.txt to get version numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.; and I want bar.txt to get version numbers 1,2,3,4, etc.
How things are workig for me currently, is that foo get "1", then if I make a change to bar and check it in next, it gets "2", see what I mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't version numbers. They are revision numbers. It tells you at which point on the last commit did the content of the revision change. What you are asking is totally pointless. If you want to do versions, then you should create tags instead.

Comment: so no reason to want what I am asking, i guess i'm used to this idea from CVS

Answer (score 0):

svn has a single global revision level, and individual items have a sparse space of versions.

You would need to do something very complex with triggers to achieve this result, which you could store on a property.

Comment: He could probably create a custom hook, but its mostly pointless in my opinion.